AWS SDK Decrypt - An error occurred (InvalidCiphertextException) when calling the Decrypt operation:
I am building a mobile application that's supposed to work offline and encrypt data offline. The application is built with ionic.
I have written an encryption service that, given a file name, encrypts the data and outputs an encrypted file.
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Filesystem, Directory, Encoding } from '@capacitor/filesystem';
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class EncryptionService {
  private encryptionKey: string;

  constructor() {
    // Initialize the encryption key (base64 encoded string)
    this.encryptionKey = environment.encryptionKey;
  }

  // Function to encrypt file content using AES
  public async encryptFile(fileName: string): Promise<void> {
    try {
      // Step 1: Read the file content
      const file = await Filesystem.readFile({
        path: fileName,
        directory: Directory.Documents,
        encoding: Encoding.UTF8, // Assuming text-based files (change if necessary)
      });

      let fileContents: string;

      // Step 2: Ensure fileContents is a string
      if (typeof file.data === 'string') {
        fileContents = file.data;
      } else {
        throw new Error('Unsupported file format, expected string.');
      }

      // Step 3: Encrypt the content using AES
      const iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(12);
      const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(fileContents, CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(this.encryptionKey), {
        iv: iv,
        format: CryptoJS.format.OpenSSL, // Using OpenSSL formatting
      });

      // Step 4: Combine the IV and ciphertext
      const combinedData = iv.concat(encrypted.ciphertext);
      const encryptedDataBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(combinedData);
      console.log('Encrypted data:', encryptedDataBase64);

      // Step 5: Write the encrypted content back to the file system
      const encryptedFileName = `encrypted_${fileName}`;

      await Filesystem.writeFile({
        path: encryptedFileName,
        data: encryptedDataBase64,
        directory: Directory.Documents,
        encoding: Encoding.UTF8,
      });

      console.log('File encrypted and saved as:', encryptedFileName);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error encrypting file:', error);
    }
  }
}

This works well, encrypts the data and all. The data is supposed to be decrypted from AWS.
The problem is, when I try to decrypt the data with the was cli, it get an error.
ENCRYPTED_DATA=$(cat encrypted_sample.txt)
DECRYPTED_DATA=$(aws kms decrypt --profile <profile-string-here> \
  --key-id <key-id-string-here> \
  --ciphertext-blob fileb://<(echo "$ENCRYPTED_DATA" | base64 --decode) \
  --region eu-west-1 \
  --query Plaintext \
  --output text)
echo "Decrypted data: $(echo "$DECRYPTED_DATA" | base64 --decode)"

I get An error occurred (InvalidCiphertextException) when calling the Decrypt operation: which makes me think the problem is with my offline decryption algorithm.
Any pointer on how what I am doing wrong?

CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(12); // Generate a random 16-byte IV

That looks wrong. Maybe it's not; I've never used the library. But it's where I'd start.

I managed to resolve the issue. I had to supply Iv for decryption. I ended up having to clearly separate the Iv from the data.

The problem was I needed to supply the Iv to the decryption process.
I had to produce the combination of the IV and the encrypted data to the decryption process.
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Filesystem, Directory, Encoding } from '@capacitor/filesystem';
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class EncryptionService {
  private dek: string;
  constructor() {
    this.dek = environment.encryptionKey;
  }

  public async encryptFile(fileName: string): Promise<void> {
    try {
      const file = await Filesystem.readFile({
        path: fileName,
        directory: Directory.Documents,
        encoding: Encoding.UTF8,
      });

      const fileContents = file.data as string;

      // Generate a 16-byte IV
      const iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);
      const key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(this.dek);

      // Encrypt using AES
      const encryptedData = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(fileContents, key, {
        iv: iv,
        format: CryptoJS.format.OpenSSL, // Using OpenSSL formatting
      });

      // Concatenate the IV and encrypted data, then convert to Base64
      const ivBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(iv);
      const encryptedDataBase64 = encryptedData.toString();

      const combinedData = ivBase64 + ':' + encryptedDataBase64; // Separate IV and encrypted data
      let encryptedFileName = `encrypted_${fileName}`;

      await Filesystem.writeFile({
        path: encryptedFileName,
        data: combinedData,
        directory: Directory.Documents,
        encoding: Encoding.UTF8,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error encrypting file:', error);
    }
  }
}


The decryption python function then  separate the IV from the encrypted data and uses the same DEK.
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import unpad
from decouple import config

def decrypt_file(encrypted_data: str, dek: str) -> str:
    # Decode the Base64 encoded key
    key = base64.b64decode(dek)

    # Split the IV and the ciphertext
    iv_base64, cipher_text_base64 = encrypted_data.split(':')
    iv = base64.b64decode(iv_base64)  # Decode the Base64 IV
    cipher_text = base64.b64decode(cipher_text_base64)  # Decode the Base64 ciphertext

    # Create AES cipher
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)

    # Decrypt and unpad the data
    decrypted_data = unpad(cipher.decrypt(cipher_text), AES.block_size)
    
    return decrypted_data.decode('utf-8')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # read encrypted sample from file
    with open('encrypted_sample.txt', 'r') as file:
        encrypted_sample = file.read()
    
    # read DEK from environment variable
    dek_base64 = config('ENCRYPTION_KEY')
    decoded_key = base64.b64decode(dek_base64)

    try:
        decrypted_text = decrypt_file(encrypted_sample, dek_base64)
        print("Decrypted Data:", decrypted_text)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Decryption failed:", str(e))


